# How can I reference the values from a piece of state that is an object in React/Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am stuck on a rather general react/redux problem:

I have a piece of state in my application which is an object. Whenever I mapStateToProps for use in my component, I am able to verify that my object is there with all its fields defined but when I try to get the value of a field I get "undefined". My approach is as follows:

customer_form_reducer.js

```
export default function(state = {}, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
   case UPDATE_CLIENT_INFO:
      console.log('Client: ', action.payload);
      console.log('First Name: ', action.payload.firstName);
      return { ...state,
        client: {
          firstName: action.payload.firstName,
          lastName: action.payload.lastName,
          homePhone: action.payload.homePhone,
          cellPhone: action.payload.cellPhone,
          email: action.payload.email,
          address: action.payload.address,
          customerMOB: action.payload.customerMOB,
          customerYOB: action.payload.customerYOB
        }
    }
  }
  return state;
}
```

I connect all my reducers in rootReducer:

index.js

```
//other import statements
import customerReducer from './customer_form_reducer';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  form,
  auth: authReducer,
  admin: adminReducer,
  client: customerReducer,
  spouse: spouseReducer,
  child: childReducer,
  other: otherReducer,
  accountId: accountIdReducer,
  customerId: customerIdReducer
});

export default rootReducer;
```

Now in my component:

customer_info_form.js

```
import { reduxForm } from 'redux-form';

class CustomerInfoForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      accountId: props.accountId,
      client: props.client,
      firstName: props.firstName,
    };

    console.log(this.state.accountId);
    console.log(this.state.client);
    console.log(this.state.client.firstName);
    console.log(this.state.firstName);
 }

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { accountId: state.accountId, client: state.client, 
firstName: state.client.firstName }
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'CustomerInfoForm',
  fields: _.keys(FIELDS),
  validate
}, mapStateToProps, { updateClientInfo })(CustomerInfoForm);
```

The first two console logs here print the correct data. The next two are my two different attempts to use/reference a value stored in my client object. Both return "undefined" even though my console claims that my client object has a defined firstName on the line above. How can I use/reference the actual values contained in my client object?

Answer (score -1):

The default state in your customer_form_reducer.js is an empty object. What values do you expect it to print?

Comment: Sorry, to clarify I am dispatching my UPDATE_CLIENT_INFO action before running this test. My actual object resulting from "console.log(this.state.client)" logs to the console with correctly populated values. Then I try to reference one of the fields and the value of the field comes back as undefined.

Comment: what is the output of the second log?

Comment: Object {firstName: "ClientName", lastName: "ClientLast", homePhone: "411", cellPhone: "511", email: "clientname@client.com"…}

It is spitting out the object. I think the issue may be that the actual values are not yet evaluated despite the object being set in my constructor. The above console log includes a warning that "Value was evaluated just now"

Comment: I'm sorry I just noticed that the logs were in your constructor. I know that for a normal component you should be able to do something like this. Perhaps you want to modify the format of the prop being passed down. If that is your aim you can write a function for that and call it on a prop in the render method. To why the issue is happening in the first place I suspect its because the props you wish to use are being passed from the redux store

Comment: The work-around I came up with was to call setState({ client: this.state.client }) in the componentWillMount() function. Seems redundant to me but I can now access the data within my object.

Comment: Why can't you reference the value straight from the redux store? Are you planning to alter it?

Comment: The piece of state in my store is an object. There are multiple fields in it I need to use to in my component. Is this approach wrong in some way I'm not realizing?

Comment: I never asked: are the values undefined in your app?

Comment: Yes the specific values return undefined when I console log or try to use them in my code. It certainly must be a lifecycle issue or something along that vein.